# Transfer class from directive html declaration to its tempate's root element

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

As per new specification from AngularJS, support for **replace: true** has been deprecated. There was a distinctive use of it which i was using it for ... but now it has been deprecated, I would like to know the how to do same thing without **replace: true**.

example

directive "myWidget" template

```css
.style1 > h3 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- current code, writing new directive to replace it -->
<div class="style1">
   <h3>title</h3>
</div>

<!-- Directive myWidget's template -->
<div class="my-widget">
   <h3>{{title}}</h3>
</div>

<!-- Directive's use in html -->
<my-widget class="style1">
</my-widget>
```

so in above example, when you use replace:true resultant output will be

```html
<!-- resultant output if replace: true, so my exisiting style will work -->
<div class="my-widget style1" title="Widget 1">
   <h3>{{title}}</h3>
</div>


<!-- resultant output if no use of replace, my existing style will not work -->
<my-widget class="style1">
   <div class="my-widget" title="Widget 1">
      <h3>{{title}}</h3>
   </div>
</my-widget>
```

So if I dont use **replace:true**, my existing CSS will not work, I have rewrite all relevant css.

so how without using replace:true I can achieve same result and transfer class defined directive when its being used in html to its template root element ?

what is the correct way to do that? I can use controller and take attribute and put that on to the templates root element but that will be writing logic to achieve just that. Will that be necessary or there is better way to do it ?